# How to lock screen while going to take a round

Tags: windows-7

I have often go on a round but can't stop downloading .....as many other people are in the same room how do I lock the screen?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will lock the screen, but only if you have set up a password for your account.

Comment: I have locked the screen of a computer that didn't have a password before. It kind of defeats the purpose though. If someone wanted to try a password and click on your user name, it would just log them in. "Windows key" + "L" will work whether or not you have a password.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>